# How to remove double quotes from a string inside JSON string?

Tags: c#, json

I am getting JSON string request from the server side. That part not handling by my self. They send the request as following (policyJson)

```
{"Data":"[{\"NAME\":\"BOARD OF INVESTMENT OF SRI LANKA\",\"STARTDATE\":\"\\\/Date(1584210600000)\\\/\",\"ENDDATE\":\"\\\/Date(1615660200000)\\\/\",\"SCOPE\":\"As per the standard SLIC \\\"Medical Expenses\\\" Policy Wordings\",\"DEBITCODENO\":1274}]","ID":200}
```

Then I Deserialize using

```
BV_response _res_pol = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BV_response>(policyJson);
```

Class **BV_response**

```
public class BV_response
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
string res = _res_pol.Data.Replace("\\", "");
var policyDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PolicyData>(res);
```

Class **PolicyData**

```
public class PolicyData
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public DateTime STARTDATE { get; set; }
    public DateTime ENDDATE { get; set; }
    public string SCOPE { get; set; }
    public int DEBITCODENO { get; set; }
}
```

For this JSON string I am getting following exception in this line

**var policyDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);**

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SHE_AppWS.Models.PolicyData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Comment: Your issue seems to be that you're trying to deserialize an array of objects into a single object. The solution would be to deserialize to a list/array of `PolicyData`. I'm not sure what the relevance of double quotes is here.

Comment: `var policyDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PolicyData[]>(res).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Why are you manipulating `res_pol.Data`? It's a perfectly valid JSON string which can be parsed. Although not into a `PolicyData` object but into a `IEnumerable<PolicyData>`

Comment: https://quicktype.io/csharp

Comment: @ZoharPeled I a getting this exception **Message = "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: M. Path '[0].SCOPE', line 1, position 149."**

Comment: Because you're removing all the escape chars... The value of `SCOPE` contains `"` which is escaped in your json using `\`, but since you're replacing all of the `\` with empty strings, it's not longer being escaped....

Comment: And as a side note, you don't need to use upper case in your c# property names. JsonConverter will happily convert to the correct properties even if the case wouldn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid JSON, and does not need string manipulation. It's just JSON stored within JSON.

> Do **not** try unescaping JSON yourself. If the JSON is not valid, get it fixed at source.

**Your problem is that you are deserializing the inner JSON to a single object, but it is an array.**

Instead, deserialize to a `List<>` or array.

```cs
BV_response _res_pol = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BV_response>(policyJson);
var policyDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PolicyData>>(_res_pol.Data);
```